# iOS swift: add kern space in the tab bar text

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar

I'm not able to add kern space into the tab bar attributed text.
The UITabBar in question is a custom tabBar, you can find the code below.

I'm using the "attributed key" dictionary to add attributes to the items title, but I'm having an issue with the kern space.

```
class ProfileTabBar: UITabBar {

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.setStyle()
}

required override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.setStyle()
}

func setStyle() {
    self.tintColor = Style.shared.primary1

    // Disable the default border
    self.layer.borderWidth = 0.0
    self.clipsToBounds = true

    // Create a new bottom border
    let bottomLine = CALayer()

    let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    //let viewForFrame = self.superview ?? self
    //let screenWidth = viewForFrame.bounds.width

    bottomLine.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: self.frame.height - 1, width: screenWidth, height: 2.0)
    bottomLine.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 235.0/255, green: 235.0/255, blue: 235.0/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
    self.layer.addSublayer(bottomLine)

    // Get the size of a single item
    let markerSize = CGSize(width: screenWidth/CGFloat(self.items!.count), height: self.frame.height)

    // Create the selection indicator
    self.selectionIndicatorImage = UIImage().createSelectionIndicator(color: self.tintColor, size: markerSize , lineWidth: 3.0)


    // Customizing the items
    if let items = self.items {
        for item in items {

            item.titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffset(horizontal: 0, vertical: -15)

            let attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey : Any] = [
                NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: Style.shared.fontBold.fontName, size: 14) as Any,
                NSAttributedStringKey.kern: NSNumber(value: 1.0)
            ]
            item.setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, for: .normal)

        }
    }

}
```

All the attributes works except for the kern. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: try to change your `1.0 as Any` to `NSNumber(value: 1.0)`

Comment: nope, it does not work

Answer (score 5):

This question is old and there is an even older answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31545610/unable-to-enable-letter-spacing-kerning-on-uitabbaritem). It appears that `UITabBarItem` appearance ignores `NSAttributedString.Key.kern`. That leaves us with a few options.

1. Subclass `UITabBarItem` this isn't easy because `UITabBarItem` inherits from `UIBarItem` which is an `NSObject` not a `UIView`.
2. Subclass `UITabBar` this can be done, but involves a decent amount of work for just some kern. You'll have to use `UIButton` instead of `UITabBarItem` so that the kern is applied.
3. You can add spacing using unicode characters in your title. This is really easy and can probably achieve the spacing you're looking for with just a few lines of code.

[Unicode spacing](http://jkorpela.fi/chars/spaces.html):

`U+0020` 1/4 em

`U+2004` 1/3 em

`U+2005` 1/4 em

`U+2006` 1/6 em

`U+2008` The width of a period “.”

`U+2009` 1/5 em (or sometimes 1/6 em)

You can use a unicode character in a `String` in Swift like this `"\u{2006}"`. That means we can insert a small space between all the characters in our tabBarItem title. Like this:

```
extension String {
  var withOneSixthEmSpacing: String {
    let letters = Array(self)
    return letters.map { String($0) + "\u{2006}" }.joined()
  }
```

Using this for our tabBarItems:

```
self.navigationController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(
    title: "Home".withOneSixthEmSpacing,
    image: homeImage,
    selectedImage: homeSelectedImage
)
```

Visually we end up with:
[image]

Instead of:

[image]

Comment: I think this should be the answer. But, how do we remove the space added to the last letter? Or exempt the last letter from the space adding?

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround is to subclass `UITabBarController`, and set the kerning in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

```
class FooTabBarController: UITabBarController {

    private var tabBarButtons: [UIControl] {
        tabBar.subviews.compactMap { $0 as? UIControl }
    }

    private var tabBarButtonLabels: [UILabel] {
        tabBarButtons.compactMap { $0.subviews.first { $0 is UILabel } as? UILabel }
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        self.tabBarButtonLabels.forEach {
            if let attributedText = $0.attributedText {
                let mutable = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: attributedText)
                mutable.addAttribute(.kern, value: 0.5, range: .init(location: 0, length: mutable.length))
                $0.attributedText = mutable
                $0.sizeToFit()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The caveats to this solution are:

1. It is somewhat fragile. It can break if Apple changes the view structure in the tab bar, ie if they stop using `UIControl`, or if they change the subview heirarchy.
2. It isn't all that efficient because the kerning has to be set every layout cycle.

Answer (score 0):

I loved [@DoesData](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7245977/doesdata)'s answer, it really helped me out a lot.

Here's a more "swifty" version of it I came up with if it helps anyone:

```
extension String {
    var withAddedSpacing: String {
        Array(self)
            .compactMap { String($0) }
            .joined(separator: "\u{2006}")
    }
}
```